# 3 dense uncountable pairwise disjoint subsets of real line

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

Can we find three dense uncountable pairwise disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R}$? If so, what are these three sets?

I feel like it's not possible.

I was trying to counter it using Baire category and trying to construct such sets using the idea of construction of Cantor set (setting elements in trinary system). But I failed in both ways. I'm not even sure if answer would be affirmative or not.

Comment: Yes, begin with three arbitrary uncountable disjoint subsets of the irrationals and find three disjoint dense subsets of the rationals. To each of the sets of irrationals adjoin one of the countable dense subsets of the rationals.

Comment: @NotMike can you explain a bit more.. some precise example would be appreciated

Comment: You can find $2^{\aleph_0}$ pairwise disjoint uncountable subsets of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Do you want to *partition* $\mathbb{R}$ into the three subsetsor just find three pairwise disjoint subsets?

Comment: @timtfj partition property is not needed as long as it serves the other conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix three disjoint dense subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$, call them $D_0, D_1$ and $D_2$.

Let $I_0=(0,1)\backslash \mathbb{Q}$, $I_1=(1,2)\backslash \mathbb{Q}$, $I_2=(2,3)\backslash \mathbb{Q}$ and set $J_k = I_k \cup D_k.$

Then, the sets $J_0, J_1$, and $J_2$ are disjoint, uncountable and dense.

Comment: So I have taken Q_p ={i/p^j: i,j integers}\Z for three different primes. Now, J_k would be union or plus?

Comment: You take the union

Comment: then is it dence in R? I can't view it properly

Comment: Yes. Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ be open then $ \emptyset \neq U\cap D_k \subset U\cap J_k$ so we have $U\cap J_k\neq \emptyset $. Which sense $U$ was arbitrary, entials each $J_k$ is dense.

Comment: ah! Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be the set of all real numbers $x$ such that $|x|$ has a decimal expansion in which all but finitely many digits are in $\{1,2,3\}$.

Let $B$ be the set of all real numbers $x$ such that $|x|$ has a decimal expansion in which all but finitely many digits are in $\{4,5,6\}$.

Let $C$ be the set of all real numbers $x$ such that $|x|$ has a decimal expansion in which all but finitely many digits are in $\{7,8,9\}$.

Now $A$, $B$, and $C$ are three disjoint uncountable dense subsets of $\mathbb R$, and $D=\mathbb R\setminus(A\cup B\cup C)$ is a fourth one.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for an uncountable partition of $\mathbb{R}$ into uncountable dense subsets.

Take first the binary fractions ( rationals with denominator a power of $2$) and leave them aside for now (a countable dense subset).

On the complement in $\mathbb{R}$ consider for each 
real number the part of the binary expansion after the dot $ \sum a_n/2^{n+1}$.
For any $\alpha \in [0,1]$ let 
\begin{eqnarray}A_{\alpha}=\{ x \ \mid \ \lim \frac{\sum_{k=0}^n a_k}{n}= \alpha \}
\end{eqnarray}

Now $A_{\alpha}$ are disjoint ( clear), uncountable ( not that hard to show), and dense. Let also $B$ formed by the binary fractions and the complement of the union of $A_{\alpha}$'s. We get our desired partition.